# Some users cannot connect to a specific page of a web app developed with React (normal connection after clearing the cache)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, caching, frontend

As a front-end developer, the company uses React to develop web apps.

However, some users report that they cannot connect to certain pages on the service.

Other pages are fine, only certain pages have problems.

After clearing the cache, I confirmed that the page was connecting normally.

So I decided it was a cache related issue and added cache invalidation code to that page.

However, even after adding the code, 1-2 inquiries per day continue to come in with the same content.

Because the company is small, there is no senior developer to discuss these issues with.

Can you give me a hint as to why the problem is happening?

I'm struggling to find the cause after work or on the weekend and can't get my head around it at all...

Any idea of even a candidate for what could be the cause would be really helpful. Thank you.

Clearing the cache made the symptoms go away, so I thought it was a cache issue and added cache invalidation code. But it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is the specail page a static page? If yes.Users in different net environment and net nodes are not the same.So some users perherps encounted cache problem.It's difficult to check.The cache content in user's net node are not updated.